# Create a firewall rule using powershell

Tags: java, powershell, firewall

I am trying to create a firewall rule for java in powershell. The problem is that even if I create exactly the same rule as windows creates automatically, it simply ignores it (I create the rule, then I start our custom company application - just normally from desktop - which uses java and then the firewall window asking about allowing or blocking traffic appears - I mean the Windows Security Alert window, which appears when you run an application for the first time). Is it somehow possible? I just want to automatically allow java through firewall in my script without the need of user interaction. 
This is the command I'm using:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Java(TM) Platform SE binary" -Direction Inbound -Program "C:\program files (x86)\common files\oracle\java\javapath_target_49433390\java.exe" -Action Allow
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add a [mcve]  related to _I start an app using java_.

Comment: There is a an example script [Add_Oracle_Java_Firewall_Rule_001.ps1](https://github.com/ThomasKur/SyntaroApplicationManagementBaseScript/blob/master/Add_Oracle_Java_Firewall_Rule_001.ps1). Maybe this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work. It creates the rules, but the firewall window appears and wants to create another ones anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the same trouble using netsh.exe when I forgot `enable=yes`

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="app name" dir=in action=allow program="Full path of .exe" enable=yes
```

So can you try to add `-Enabled True` to your command line.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for some reason. When i did it without the enable parameter, there was "enable=yes" in the description also. But when i explicitly specified it in the command, it magically worked, I don't understand. Thank you again.